# How to prohibit user from viewing a page before a specific time period?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to build an online quiz test site.

Suppose, exam will start at 10:00 am and a student login to give exam at 9:45 am. Whenever the student clicks 'Take Exam' button, he/she cannot not get access to the question paper because the exam time is 10:00 am and there are still 15 minutes before the exam start.

Now I want to put some Javascript or PHP code that will prohibit the students to give exam earlier and if a students come early, it will show a stopwatch which display the remaining time before exam time and when the current time is equal to exam time then he/she will be directly redirected to the question paper page.

Comment: A simple `if (time() < /* start time */)` on the PHP side and a timer in Javascript will do it. Have you tried anything?

Comment: File under "How to start my project on [x]".

Comment: By 10 am, you do mean in server time right?

Comment: You might consider hiding the button (or show it disabled) until it's time.  Generally better to prevent invalid actions from happening in the first place.

Comment: yes 10 am , is the server time @ Jared Farrish

Answer (score 2):

Anythign client-side is hackable. Stick to pure server side.

Why not a very simple PHP page which, when loaded, checks the time and redirects appropriately?

test.php

```
   if ( now() < $test_start_time)  
   {  
     header('Location: come_back_later.php');  
     Die;  
   }  
   // test page goes here
```

Comment: Thanks. I am now looking to setup the stopwatch on the come_back_letter.php page. @Mawg

Comment: To make a stopwatch you _could_ use JavaScript. It doesn't matter if they try to hack it; that will just frustrate them. If you google, I am sure you will find such a script

Comment: Or, you could do it in PHP by using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh  When the page is loaded, just subtract current time from start time to show how long is left

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust JavaScript for this since the user can disable Javascript on his/her browser to bypass the security. You should look at some server-side approach, perhaps some script that would publish your website at the specific given date and time.

You did not specify your OS and web server, but whether you use Linux/Apache or Windows/IIS, doing something like this from a batch script shouldn't be too difficult.

**UPDATE**

Have 2 landing pages for your app, one with a body saying something along the lines of `this app will be available starting at 10 AM` and create a Task (`Control Panel-> Admin Tools -> Task Scheduler`) that would replace this temporary landing page with the real one at 10 AM of the given date. Is that easy enough?

Comment: I am using Widows operating system @Iacrus

Comment: +1 for "wouldn't trust JavaScript for this for obvious reasons" - although it ought ot have been "wouldn't trust client-side".

Comment: @Mawg: Added a little more details as to why Javascript shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: +1 I am personally not a big fan of JS, because users tend to edit it then complain to me when it doesn't work. In this case, it is very tempting to hack it, but I don't want to say "don't trust JS" ... ever. In this case it is simpler to say "don't trust client side" as you proved by cleverly chaning the system clock, which doesn't affect the JS at all.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of every PHP script you want to disallow early access to, you would want to include something like:

```
if (mktime(12, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2012) > time()) {
    require 'waiting.php';
    die;
}
```

You should check the [mktime() PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to learn how to specify the date and time you wish you use as the threshold.

The above example would [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the `waiting.php` script when the current time is less than *Midday, on the 1st of Jan, 2011)*. The `die` function prevents the PHP from loading anything else in the page, effectively preventing access. When the current time exceeds your `mktime()` time, the `include` and `die` calls will never be trigger, and the page will be loaded as per normal.

**Be wary of the system time.** `mktime()` will use the system's time, which may be a different timezone than the one in which you want to run your test. You should use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set your timezone *before* calling `mktime()`.

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Lastly. as mentioned in other comments, JavaScript detection *alone* is not reliable, not only because it can be easily circumvented, but also because there is no guarantee that the user's time is the same as the server's.

Say you wanted to refresh the page once the timeout is complete. I would include in `waiting.php` the following:

```
<?php
    $miliseconds_remaining = (mktime(12, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011) - time()) * 1000;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.reload(true);
    }, <?php echo $miliseconds_remaining;?>);
</script>
```

This will force the page to automatically refresh, and ignore the browser's cache, when the time expires. This solution will refresh the page irregardless of timezone differences between the server and the user.